# Specifying custom tenant id in REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In SOAP Teanant API I can define my own tenantId (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Tenants+with+APIs#ManagingTenantswithAPIs-addTenant()), but in REST API this ability is not available. The reason I wanted to use custom tenantId is so that I can map multi-tenancy from WSO2 domain to my application domain, thus using id as a bridge. There is additonalClaims element in request JSON for addTenant endpoint, but this element is not returned in getTenant endpoint. Is there additional tenant property I can use to store custom information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tenant creation REST API doesn't allow to input the tenant id. But you can use the returned tenant id for the mapping purpose.
Once a tenant is created successfully using [API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/tenant-management-rest-api/#/Tenants/addTenant), It should return `201 Cretaed status` code and you would be able to find the `Location header` in the response headers. The location header contains the location to the tenant. `https://<Host>:<port>/t/<tenant-domain>/api/server/v1/tenants/<tenant-id>`. From this value you can extract the tenant id.

For the second part of the question:
`additonalClaims` attribute belongs to `tenant owners` not to the core tenant object. When you execute GET /tenants or GET /tenants/ request, owner's id and username are returned.

```
 "owners": [
        {
            "id": "af01d6cf-bf5d-440f-b99c-ac482f6dc89f",
            "username": "kim"
        }
    ]
```

If you check the tenant owner's profile via carbon console/console you should see the additional claims added via the request. Moreover, if that added local claim is mapped to a SCIM claim (eg: http://wso2.org/claims/mobile) you would view that user properties via [SCIM GET User API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/getUser%20by%20id).

eg: `https://<host>:<port>/t/<tenant-domain>/scim2/Users/<tenant-ownser's-id>`

Comment: I realize that I can use tenantId in my domain, I wanted the process to be bottom up. I'll work with what's available. Thank you.